# Is there any way to use Microsoft Store API in WPF Application (DesktopBridge) for inApp purchases?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

While trying to bring WPF Apps in Windows Store using Desktop Bridge.

Is there any way to use Microsoft Store API in WPF Application (Desktop Bridge) for inApp purchases ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You could use [StoreContext Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext?view=winrt-22000) in desktop applications via desktop bridge. What you need is to configure the StoreContext object to specify which application window is the owner window for modal dialogs that are shown by the object.

You could refer to this document fore more detailed steps: [Using the StoreContext class with the Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#desktop)

Comment: The current WPF project's .NET Version is 4.6.1   So i think i have to upgrade to 5.0 or 6.0 and then follow steps mentioned.. Am i right ?

Comment: @Neha The document also contains steps for **earlier versions of .NET or C++**, it just under the parts of .net 5

Comment: Hi @Roy-li-msft  Thanks, I am able to compile code that uses store api in WPF.  but now stuck with how to debug store api code in WPF?   (In UWP first step was to associate app with store, but what is the workaround here. so that i can get right StoreContext; duing debug.  any guidance?

Comment: @Neha So as you mentioned, the first step is to associate the app with the store. Have you do that for your desktop bridge application?

Comment: @Roy-li-msft :   No. desktop application does not have " associate the app" option.  I build packaging project to publish to store.

Comment: @Neha Are you using the Windows application package project to package your WPF application? The windows application package project could use the association function.

Comment: (Note: This app's old version was installed from store earlier , so license is acquired.  ) Yes, I tried that yesterday. Packaging Project -> Associated with Store App -> Build Package-> Installed package -> Run the installed App, then I did debug->attach process , but symbols where not loaded.  then I went to modules window and force loaded the symbols but debugger skips all steps/lines related to Store API code.  So I am stuck here.   @Roy-li-msft

Comment: @Neha Please try to test your in-app purchase function in a new device that haven't purchased the add-ons before.